# Repeater - Save data in viewstate with the Dropdownlist selection change action?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help in the technical approach with the following scenario:-

1) A dropdownlist with some options. It has a postback action on the selectedIndexChange server side event handler. For example, lets say it contains language options such as english, french etc.

2) Repeater with a label and the textbox control. For example label is Emp Name and textbox is containing the Emp Designation. We have to save emp designation in the various languages.

3) Every time i pick something from the dropdown, i have to flip the textbox control and fill the form. Now i want to save the given data of the texbox in the viewstate. So that every time, the user changes the dropdown selection, he can see the repeater data corresponding to the dropdown selection.

4) I guess some kind of relationship between the dropdown option and the repeater data is needed. But how can we make this thing work.

Now which is the best technique to save the data on the server side? I have to keep it in the viewstate.

I hope my question makes sense and clear the problem scenario. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a repeater why not just have a dropdown along with a textbox and some labels, then when the dropdown value changes pull the matching values from viewstate and load the textboxes and labels. Then just use a button to save the changes which would add/update the list that you are maintaining in viewstate.

Comment: i have to use repeater because the labels and textbox can vary in number. They are not fixed.